# Implicit differentiation using unconvential quotient rule

Tags: calculus, derivatives, implicit-differentiation

Find $\frac {dy}{dx}$

For x = $\frac {2y}{x^2 - y}$

I have solved this in the easy route of multiplying by (x^2 - y).

The final answer is: $\frac {dy}{dx}$ = (3x^2 - y) / (x+2)

I want to solve using the quotient rule, directly but I can't do it. Here is my solution/working out.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ay8aX.jpg

Thnx x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$ x' = \frac{2y'}{x^2-y} - \frac{2y(2x x' - y')}{(x^2-y)^2} = \frac{2y'-x(2xx'-y')}{x^2-y} = \frac{(x+2)y'-2x^2x'}{x^2-y}, $$
replacing the extra $2y/(x^2-y)$. 
So
$$ \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{x^2-y+2x^2}{x+2} $$
and so on.

It's certainly not that obvious where to replace the values to get the given form: there are plenty of alternatives, not least solving for $y$ directly to get
$$ y = \frac{x^3}{x+2} $$
and just differentiating that.

Comment: Thank you for your reply sir. That is excellent advice, in future I will put it in your form or just avoid the fractional form.

Answer (score 0):

Differentiating with respect to $x$ we have by the quotient rule: $$1=\frac{2\frac{\mathrm d y}{\mathrm d x}(x^2-y)-(2x-\frac{\mathrm d y}{\mathrm d x})2y}{(x^2-y)^2}$$
so rearranging we have $$\frac{\mathrm d y}{\mathrm d x}=\frac{(x^2-y)^2+4xy}{2x^2}=\frac{(x^2-y)^2+4xy}{4\frac y x + 2y}=\frac{x(x^2-y)^2+4x^2y}{2y(x+2)}=\frac{4\frac{y^2}x+4x^2y}{2y(x+2)}=\frac{2\frac y x + 2x^2}{x+2}=\frac{3x^2-y}{x+2}$$ as required.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I do not understand how you let: 2x^2 = 4y/x  + 2y after you write dy/dx in the first and second part. But thanks again.

Comment: I see what you did, this is very clever .